# How to replace certain forward slashes differently with regex?

Tags: python, regex, string

Lets say I have these strings:

```
this_string = 'US/Canada'

that_string = '/fowardslash @/t t/'
```

I want to be able to `re.sub()` the strings with these 2 goals:

1) replace all the `/` that does **not** have letters before and after it with nothing `''`.

2) replace all the `/` that **HAS** a letter before and after it with a space.

So what I want to end up with would be something like this:

```
this_string = 'US Canada'

that_string = 'forwardslash @t t'
```

---

I currently have this `re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9\s]+','', this_string)`

which does the 1st goal but not the 2nd.

I would get `this_string = 'USCanada'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use re.sub() with own replace function.

Example:

```
import re

this_string = 'US/Canada'
that_string = '/fowardslash @/t t/'

def myreplace(match):
    if match.group(1) is not None and match.group(2) is not None:
        return match.group(1) + ' ' + match.group(2)
    else:
        return ''

print(re.sub(r'(?:([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+))|(/)', myreplace, this_string))
print(re.sub(r'(?:([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+))|(/)', myreplace, that_string))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.sub('\/', ' ', this_string)` for second goal, `\` will escape the `/` character and results to what you need.

But I don't think if it's possible to use same pattern for 2 different scenarios, you can use patterns together to achieve what you want

Comment: That's not a complete answer to OP's question

Comment: @RaunakAgarwal does it feel like it's a complete answer to OP's question now?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the other way round?

```
text = re.sub(r'\b/\b' , ' ' , text) # Replace with space
text = re.sub(r'/'     , ''  , text) # Remove
```

Or:

```
text = re.sub(r'/', '', re.sub(r'\b/\b', ' ', text))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
import re
s = '''US/Canada
/fowardslash @/t t/'''
rx = r'(?<=[^\W\d_])/(?=[^\W\d_])|(/)'
print(re.sub(rx, lambda m: '' if m.group(1) else ' ', s))
# => US Canada
#    fowardslash @t t
```

See the [Python 3 demo online](https://ideone.com/eP1p48).

The regex matches

- `(?<=[^\W\d_])/(?=[^\W\d_])` - a `-` surrounded with any Unicode letter
- `|` - or
- `(/)` - (Capturing group 1) a `/` char in any other context.

If Group 1 is not empty, if it matched, the match is removed, else, it is replaced with a space.